# Sitecore Content editor pop up/ New tab does not publish items

Tags: sitecore

I have created a custom asp.net search module in an Iframe to search Sitecore items,

I have implemented a link on that module to view each Sitecore item in the content editor. Since I call this as a pop up from code behind I use following code. It actually works fine.

```
string url = string.Format("{0}/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Editor?id={1}&vs={2}&la={3}&fo={1}&sc_content=master", serverUrl, item.ID.ToString(), item.Version.ToString(), item.Language.ToString());

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "OpenClassifiedItem", string.Format("window.open('{0}','_blank');", url), true);
```

When I click on the link, Sitecore item opens up in a pop up, and the item get selected from the content tree. I can edit and save, changes gets saved.
But I can not publish the item (or any item) using this pop up. Publishing works fine in the parent window. It only does not work in pop up window. It does not even open up the publishing wizard. 
Why is this happening? Seems like Publishing events do not gets fired. 
(Sitecore 6.6 update 5)

Comment: Are you running this app from within the Sitecore Shell? Does it work if you use SheerResponse.Eval("window.open('" + url + "','_blank');") instead of using the ScriptManager?

Comment: Hi Jens, you have actually understood the problem, SheerResponse.Eval  did not work for me as I run it in my web app context, I tried that.It's not running within the shell. Is that the reason publishing does not get invoked? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem, this is happening even SheerResponse.Eval is used instead of ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. And I found out that this occurs only for Sitecore users whose profile start url is set to Desktop(In Edit user popup Profile tab) and only when the item is in a final workflow state. For any other case it works as expected.